# create dynamic dropdown menu using an map of strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

html will look like

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <label>Status</label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <div class="input-group">
     <div class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
     </div>
      
     <select class="form-control pull-right" name="status" id="status" tabindex="2">
  <option value="1">Enable</option>
                <option value="0">Disable</option>
            </select>
        
            <select class="form-control pull-right" name="status_reason" id="status_reason" tabindex="2">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value=""></option>
                 <option value=""></option>
          <option value=""></option>
            </select>
      
    </div><!-- /.input group -->
```

After user selects status from status dropdown box that is either enabled or disabled one more dropdown should be displayed(i.e status_reason dropdown) depending on selection of status dropdown. The dynamic values will be there stored in a map containing string as key and value.

Comment: where is your map containing strings?

Comment: its dynamic for example var m map[string]string

Comment: dynamic means, are you going to fetch it via Ajax on change of first DD or it will be present on page?

Comment: dynamic means it will be there in the map.which i will be getting via beego server(golang)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need something like this. For now I have hard coded the map values but you can assign those variable with your own source.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var map0 = new Object(); // or var map = {};
  map0["value0_0"] = "reason0_0";
  map0["value0_1"] = "reason0_1";
  map0["value0_2"] = "reason0_2";

  var map1 = new Object(); // or var map = {};
  map1["value1_0"] = "reason1_0";
  map1["value1_1"] = "reason1_1";
  map1["value1_2"] = "reason1_2";

  var reasons = [map0, map1];

  $("#status").change(function(){
  
    $("#status_reason").empty();
  
    var selected_status = $(this).val();
    var reason_value_map = reasons[parseInt(selected_status)]

    for(var k in reason_value_map) 
    {
      $("#status_reason").append('<option   value="'+k+'">'+reason_value_map[k]+'</option>');
    }
  
  
  });
  
  $("#status").change(); //populate the second DD on document ready
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <label>Status</label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <div class="input-group">
     <div class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
     </div>
      
     <select class="form-control pull-right" name="status" id="status" tabindex="2">
  <option value="1">Enable</option>
                <option value="0">Disable</option>
            </select>
        
            <select class="form-control pull-right" name="status_reason" id="status_reason" tabindex="2">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value=""></option>
                 <option value=""></option>
          <option value=""></option>
            </select>
      
    </div><!-- /.input group -->
```